# Issues with creating a code to find derivatives for a simple polynomial

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA code to find the derivative of a simple polynomial. I organized the code in a way that I have to input the coefficient at the first ("A") row of the excel sheet followed by the power at the second ("B") row of the excel sheet over a range of 12 columns. The user will then manually write 12 domains from row 3 to row 14 for which he wants to find the respective derivatives. I will just need to start the subroutine and the derivatives would be found from row 3 to row 14, at the cell beside their respective domains. The following is my code:

```
 Sub derivativecalculator()
'Declare variables
 Dim domain As Double
 Dim coefficient As Double
 Dim derivative As Double
 Dim power As Double
'Associating cells with letters to use asterisk sign in the for next loop
  Cells(1, 1).Value = AA1
  Cells(1, 2).Value = BB1
  Cells(1, 3).Value = CC1
  Cells(1, 4).Value = DD1
  Cells(1, 5).Value = EE1
  Cells(1, 6).Value = FF1
  Cells(1, 7).Value = GG1
  Cells(1, 8).Value = HH1
  Cells(1, 9).Value = II1
  Cells(1, 10).Value = JJ1
  Cells(1, 11).Value = KK1
  Cells(1, 12).Value = LL1
  Cells(2, 1).Value = AA2
  Cells(2, 2).Value = BB2
  Cells(2, 3).Value = CC2
  Cells(2, 4).Value = DD2
  Cells(2, 5).Value = EE2
  Cells(2, 6).Value = FF2
  Cells(2, 7).Value = GG2
  Cells(2, 8).Value = HH2
  Cells(2, 9).Value = II2
  Cells(2, 10).Value = JJ2
  Cells(2, 11).Value = KK2
  Cells(2, 12).Value = LL2
'Using for-next loop to determine derivatives across a range of values using general derivative formula up to power 12
   For currow = 3 To 14
   Cells(currow, 1).Value = domain
   derivative = AA1 * AA2 * domain ^ (AA2 - 1) + BB1 * BB2 * domain ^ (BB2 - 1) + CC1 * CC2 * domain ^ (CC2 - 1) + DD1 * DD2 * domain ^ (DD2 - 1) + EE1 * EE2 * domain ^ (EE2 - 1) + FF1 * FF2 * domain ^ (FF2 - 1) + GG1 * GG2 * domain ^ (GG2 - 1) + HH1 * HH2 * domain ^ (HH2 - 1) + II1 * II2 * domain ^ (II2 - 1) + JJ1 * JJ2 * domain ^ (JJ2 - 1) + KK1 * KK2 * domain ^ (KK2 - 1) + LL1 * LL2 * domain ^ (LL2 - 1)
   derivative = Cells(currow, 2).Value
   Next arrow
End Sub
```

As shown in the above code, I declared my variables, and associated the values in the first and second row over a range of 12 columns with variables. I than substituted those variables in the derivative general formula and used a for-next loop to find the corresponding derivative for each and every domain before getting my code to display the result at the cell next to the respective domain. I have tried to run the subroutine, but excel deems there to be a logical flaw in my code. I am unable to find any errors in my code, do you see any logical errors present that I have missed?

Comment: Sorry the original poster here, please ignore the second last line in next arrow, it is next currow, i made a typo

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question if there's a typo.